# Есть ли готовое решение по перемещению блоков в ангуляре?

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui

Здравствуйте!

Использую для перетаскиваний модуль **ngDraggable**. Так же использовал **ui-sortable**. Но не в одном нельзя просто перемещать элементы по странице, как, например, в **jQuery UI**.

Необходимо что бы элементы можно было перемещать, задавать и запоминать координаты.

Есть ли готовое решение?
Или подскажите как можно подружить *angular* и *jQuery UI*?
Спасибо)

**UPD:** вроде нашёл что-то [похожее](http://siongui.github.io/2013/04/04/angularjs-draggable-movable-element/), но не совсем понимаю как потом задавать координаты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Долгие поиски наконец то привели меня к [ответу](https://github.com/Tuch/angular-dnd)!
На мой взгляд очень функциональный и гибкий модуль.